# PHP images not loading

Tags: wordpress, loading

I am having issues with images not always loading on my site. In some cases I have noticed that no images whatsoever load (screenshot one) and in others everything loads fine (screenshot two).

I don't know the exact causes, but it has to be linked to wordpress surely? The only images which don't load are from the wordpress loop (the article headline images) and all of the graphics which I have created load fine.

I am using a php cropper called TimThumb.

[Screenshot one](http://www.touringcars.net/NoImageLoad.png)

[Screenshot two](http://www.touringcars.net/ImageLoad.png)

Has anyone any ideas why the images aren't always loading and what can be done to improve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `cropper.php` runs out of memory before it serves the images.

Comment: Plausible. What would cause it to sometimes run out of memory, and other times not run out. If it is being asked to crop 20 or 30 images on a page as opposed to 5 or 10?

Comment: More images and more request => more memory consumption. The dimensions of the images are also significant. If it runs out of memory, there should be an entry on your `error_log`. I suggest you to make `cropper.php` to save the cropped images, in order not to recreate them on every request.

Comment: Cropper.php is creating images on every request and saving them in a directory called '/cache'. I believe that it is saving images every time, even if they have already been created. I'm not sure how to make it only create them once and then call on the saved images. Cue head-scratching...

Comment: FYI I am using the TimThumb cropper.